# How can I locate a tag via CSS selectors, referencing the content of a sibling tag?

Tags: css, ruby, xml, nokogiri, siblings

I'm working on a Ruby script that will parse and manipulate some XML files. I'm using Nokogiri for the XML handling.

The problem I have is that there are several constructs like this one:

```
<USER_ELEMENT>
  <NAME>ATTRIBUTE01</NAME>
  <VALUE>XXX</VALUE>
</USER_ELEMENT>
```

I need to set the `<VALUE>` tag that's within the same  of a particular `<VALUE>ATTRIBUEnn</VALUE>`. My current approach is using

```
xml.css('USER_ELEMENT').find { |node| node.at_css('NAME').text == 'ATTRIBUTEnn'}.at_css('VALUE').content = 'NEW_VALUE'
```

but it looks rather ugly.

I'm wondering which would be a cleaner way of dealing with the situation?

Comment: Does it have to be CSS? XPath might be a better choice.

Comment: As I already answered in the other answers' threads, the choice of CSS is for consistency. The entire application relies on CSS selectors, so I'd rather to stick to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The css selector for siblings is ~:

```
xml.at('USER_ELEMENT > NAME[text()="ATTRIBUTE01"] ~ VALUE').content = 'NEW_VALUE'
```

Comment: Just to add up, @Phrogz answer also works. The reason why I'm marking this one as correct is because it uses CSS, while the former uses XPath. I have no problems with XPath, but the entire application is written using CSS locators, so I'd rather stick to it for consistency.

Answer (score 3):

Using XPath:

```
attnn = "ATTRIBUTE01"
xml.at_xpath("//USER_ELEMENT[NAME='#{attnn}']/VALUE").content = "Yay"
puts xml
#=> <USER_ELEMENT>
#=>   <NAME>ATTRIBUTE01</NAME>
#=>   <VALUE>Yay</VALUE>
#=> </USER_ELEMENT>
```

In English, that XPath says:

- `//USER_ELEMENT` - find elements with this name anywhere in the document
- `[…]` - but only if…

  - `NAME="ATTRIBUTE01"` - …you can find a child `NAME` element with this text
- `/VALUE` - and now find the child `VALUE` elements of these

Comment: I figured you'd show up soon enough to give me another quick XPath lesson, that's nicer than the one I had in mind.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's even a bit cleaner than the CSS one, but as I said I want to keep CSS in this project for consistency.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if nokogiri supports CSS3, but if it does, this should work

```
xml.css('USER_ELEMENT NAME:content("ATTRIBUTEnn") + VALUE').content = "NEW_VALUE"
```

Comment: It does support CSS3, but apparently only to some extent. `content` is not supported, but it didn't complain about `text`. The problem is that is simply chose to ignore the `text` filter, and dumped me all `<USER_ELEMENT>` nodes...